# How is does Jquery display a tooltip on this span element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've been asked to edit a web page that I didn't create and I'm trying to understand some code in it.  I have a list item that contains a span.  The span only has a class attribute, no alt text or title.

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info"></span>
```

The ui-icon and ui-icon-info classes are from JqueryUI.  They display a information icon as a background image for the span.  I don't see anything else special about the css:

```
.ui-icon-info { background-position: -16px -144px; }
.ui-icon { width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(ui-icons_72a7cf_256x240.png); }
.ui-icon { text-indent: -99999px; overflow: hidden; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

When a user hovers over the icon it displays a div as a tooltip:

```
<div class="tooltip" style="position: absolute; top: 661px; left: 710px; opacity: 0.8; display: none;">Some Tooltip Text</div>
```

The css for tooltip also doesn't look to be anything special.  Just some formatting info.
There are several of these span elements in the list and I can't figure out how it is choosing the correct div to display in the tooltip.  Can someone please tell me how Jquery selects the correct div to display for the tooltip of a span element?

Comment: I think Javascript is your missing link

Comment: Is the div already in the DOM ? Where ?

Comment: Can you show us some HTML a Fiddle or the actual page?

Comment: Here is the actual page:  http://www.usda.gov/energy/maps/html/resources.htm  The tooltip div is already in the dom and displayed as hidden.

Comment: @NBabel It wasn't me... Here, i'll upvote you

Comment: @Alon sorry, guess I didn't see it right.  BTW - the div is probably being displayed with javascript somewhere.  I just didn't know if this is builtin to the Jquery tooltip.  I can't see where the event would be happening.  Thanks.

Comment: It can be an external JS file, or inline script. We must see the complete page to answer this question

Comment: I added a link to the live page above.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function called `loadReportFunctions()` where it perfoms an ajax request and calls to the function `formatLinks(links)` . There it plays with the properties of the `span.ui-icon` elements.

[image: Chrome Resources Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks very much, I hadn't seen that.